# Setting subdomains on Localhost

Tags: dns, localhost

I'm trying to test a multi-tenant application locally by setting a subdomain on localhost.

The application is currently running on localhost:5252.

In my hosts file I added the following:

```
127.0.0.1       contoso.localhost
```

and then in IIS on my default Web Site, I added a binding to contoso.localhost, pointing to that same port.

All I ever get when navigating to contoso.localhost is a blank IIS page though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you did it right, do you have any log files? And what happens when you goto `http:\\contoso.localhost:5252`?

Comment: @Alex I get the default IIS page, even if I specify the port.  What log files should I look at?  Total noob here :/

Answer (score 0):

You added it to your hosts. You still have to set it up in your web-server, like in Apache.
That's why you get a blank page, Apache (for example) redirects you back.

Comment: I tried setting it up in IIS - I added a binding for contoso.localhost at port 5252, still not working though.